# How to write a Visual Studio extension for a template or markup language that supports embedded code snippets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, vsx, viewengine

Is it possible to write an extension for Visual Studio 2010 that provides syntax highlighting, intellisense, outlining, etc **for a custom template or markup language supporting embedded code snippets**, similar to the tooling for Razor in ASP .NET MVC 3? Can this be done without using private APIs, without access to Microsoft-internal documentation and, *most importantly*, **without having to reimplement syntax highlighting, intellisense, etc. for the embedded programming language** (i.e. C# or VB)?

The SDK documentation [seems to suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240.aspx#projection) that the Visual Studio editor supports embedded languages via [***projection buffers***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.projection.aspx), but it doesn't really give any details or examples. Some of the "legacy interop interfaces used for the editor and language services" in [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.aspx) also seem to be relevant, e.g. [IVsTextBufferCoordinator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextbuffercoordinator.aspx), but the documentation doesn't say much about how all these pieces fit together.

Provided that projection buffers actually do what I hope, where can I hook into the editor to replace a normal text buffer with a projection buffer?

Does maybe anyone have more information on the APIs relevant for supporting embedded languages or could point me into the right direction?

Comment: I'm also looking for pointers to do this. Did you ever find any resources on this?

Comment: No, and I eventually gave up on my project due to the sorry state of the relevant SDK documentation (and SDK functionality?).

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/SparkSense as an example. It was built for the spark view engine to provide intellisense for VS 2010.

"SparkSense is a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 that enables various tooling support and productivity features when using Spark as a View Engine for various MVC frameworks including ASP.NET MVC"

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, it seems that SparkSense implements its own limited kind of "intellisense" for the embedded code snippets. I think Robert calls it "type completion". It doesn't reuse the Visual Studio C# language service and it's not the full intellisense as e.g. available in Razor pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own editor extension, see this article : http://www.devx.com/VS_2010/Article/45058

And to understand how it works : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240(v=VS.100).aspx

Do research about "Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) "

You can download an exemple for the Ook langage [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ookLanguage)

Comment: I'm well aware of the available SDK documentation and my question actually contains a link to the same MSDN page you've linked.